# Which LayoutManager should I use for my main frame's content pane?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

Here is a screenshot of my current GUI:

[image: Current GUI]

I do not know which LayoutManager to use for my main frame's content pane.  In the picture, you can see that the main window is logically divided into a left and a right section - the left section has the search components and the right section is the output.

From what I have read, it looks like either a BorderLayout or GridBagLayout would work, but then I read further about this MigLayout and that seems like it would work also.  I am also confused about what LayoutManagers to use internally on each side.  Basically I'm just confused now with information overload, and don't know what to use, so I thought I would ask professional programmers what they would use in this case.

Comment: I'm not profesional, nor programmer, but everything depeds of how the childs are resizable together with container, isn't about good practicies to layout whole JFrame by using only one LayoutManager, you can to combine (put there a few JPanels) or to use the same LayoutManager for JFrames child that represents JPanel, then final output will be very different as by using only GBC or MigLayout   for whole JFrame, sure depand of if JComponent will be resisable or not

Comment: first step (before thinking LayoutManager) is to have a picture of how it _should_ look like (good ol' pencil and paper serve well :) Screenshots of actually coded screens are not so helpful, because most of the time they show what went wrong (yours above has several alignment/usability issues)

Comment: I realize there are alignment issues, but could you point out the usability issues?

Comment: could all be perfect from the domain knowledge, so take it with a grain of salt, it might be only me :-) The search field in the _middle_ looks rather unusual, also what are the buttons adding/removing - they seem kind of free-floating without much coherence to anything

Comment: The buttons are to add, remove and edit product records.  The box in the middle of the left side is a JTable that populates with product records when you use the drop-down JComboBoxes above.  The search field actually filters the results in the JTable by narrowing them down as you type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which Layout Manager should I use for my main frame's content pane?

That's the easy question.  You should use a `FlowLayout` or a `BorderLayout`, because most Swing GUI's should have one main `JPanel`.

### Complex GUI

Your real question is a bit harder.  You have a complex GUI layout, which will require more than one `JPanel` and more than one layout manager.

The following comments are my first impression.  I reserve the right to make changes based on testing the actual coding of the GUI.

### Right Side

The right side of the GUI requires a `JTabbedPane`.  I can only see one of the `JPanel`s in the `JTabbedPane`.  The layout manager for that `JPanel` is a `GridBagLayout`.

### Left Side

The left side of the GUI requires 4 `JPanel`s inside of a `JPanel`.  The layout manager for the left side `JPanel` is a `BoxLayout`, Y axis.

The top `JPanel` of the 4 `JPanel`s on the left side uses a `GridBagLayout`.

The upper middle `JPanel` is made up of two `JPanel`s.  The first `JPanel` uses a `BoxLayout`, Y axis, to hold a `JLabel` and a `JList`.  The second `JPanel` uses a `GridBagLayout` to hold 3 buttons.  The `GridBagLayout` is necessary to get the button spacing.

The lower middle `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` to hold a `JLabel` and `JTextField`.

The bottom `JPanel` holds 2 button groups.  The first group has a title, while the second group doesn't  The layout manager for the `JPanel` is a `BoxLayout`, X axis.

### Conclusion

If you understood all of this, great.  Build your GUI one `JPanel`per Java class, testing to make sure that the Swing components lay out the way you expect.  Maximize and manually change the size of the `JFrame` window to see if the GUI changes in the way you expect.

I would guess that it would take me 32 to 40 hours of work to put this GUI together.  If you were to use a window builder, it would probably take 400 to 600 hours of work to put this GUI together.

Don't use a window builder.  It will only complicate connecting the Swing components.

If you didn't understand my comments, I don't know that you made it down to the bottom of my answer to read this.  :-)

Study the [Oracle Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).  Don't skip over anything.  Go through the entire tutorial, more than once if necessary, so that you may understand Swing.  Learning takes time.

Comment: _left side of the GUI requires 4_ actually, no: nesting panels is just one option, not necessarily the best (cross-panel alignment tends to be a pain, as we all know ;)

Comment: @kleopatra: For you, nothing is required.  For a Swing beginner, nesting panels is a lot easier than cross component alignment.

Comment: Thanks very much for the highly detailed response.  I understand what you are saying in general, but I will study the Oracle Swing Tutorial to learn more.  Thank you again.

Comment: maybe wasn't clear enough: nesting panels will throw the _newbie_ into alignment hell :-) In the above f.i. all the labels need to be vertically aligned with one edge (as well as the labelled components to their respective right) - that's near-to impossible with nesting. Also, you throw them into gridbag hell - if they are supposed to master that monster, they could use it for everything and all-in-one.

Comment: "The upper middle JPanel is made up of two JPanels. The first JPanel uses a BoxLayout, Y axis, to hold a JLabel and a JList. The second JPanel uses a GridBagLayout to hold 3 buttons. The GridBagLayout is necessary to get the button spacing."  That's actually not a JLabel and a JList.  It's just a single JTable.  Would that change your recommendation for that region?

Comment: @Bri: I'd put the JTable in a JScrollPane, whether or not you expect the table to scroll.  Table headers work better in a JScrollPane.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, I'm not a big fan of nesting panels (not anymore, since I discovered powerful and yet easy-to-master third-party managers :-) My current favourite is MigLayout, so here's an all-in-one version:

[image]

The vertical line highlights a notorious problem that nested layouts do have: alignment across panels is not supported (though there are tricks to achieve it). My recommendation would be to learn mastering one of the big three (MigLayout, JGoodies FormLayout, DesignGridbagLayout) and then do most layouts without nesting.

```
MigLayout layout = new MigLayout(
        // auto-wrap after 4 columns
        "wrap 5", 
        // 5 columns:
        // 1. labels, 2./3. radiobuttons, 
        // 4. buttons, 5. tabbedPane
        "[][fill, sg][fill, sg]u[fill]para[fill, grow]",
        // 7 rows:
        // 1. - 6. default for combos/buttons, 
        // 7. growing table
        // > 7 default 
        // unrelated gaps before/after the table
        "[][][]u[][][][grow, fill]u[]r[]");

JComponent content = new JPanel(layout);
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.addTab("SomeTab", new JPanel()); 
String[] labels = { "Company:", "Product Type:", "Product:" };
for (String string : labels) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel(string);
    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
    content.add(label);
    if (string.equals(labels[0])) {
        content.add(combo, "span 2");
        // make span all rows, 
        // force a min width 
        content.add(tabbedPane, "skip 1, spany, grow, wmin 500");
    } else {
        content.add(combo, "span 2, wrap");
    }
};
// JXTable supports specifying the visibleRowCount
JXTable table = new JXTable(0, 1);
table.setVisibleRowCount(10);
content.add(new JScrollPane(table), "span 3, spany 4, grow");
String[] buttons = {"Add", "Remove", "Edit"};
for (String string : buttons) {
    content.add(new JButton(string));
}
content.add(new JLabel("Search:"), "newline, skip 2");
JTextField field = new JTextField(12);
content.add(field, "span 2");
content.add(new JLabel("Show only:"), "newline");
String[] checks = {"A", "B", "C"};
String skip = "";
for (String string : checks) {
    content.add(new JCheckBox(string), skip);
    content.add(new JRadioButton(string.toLowerCase()), "wrap");
    skip = "skip";
}
// decorate to show vertical alignment line
DebugLayerUI ui = new DebugLayerUI(field);
JLayer layer = new JLayer(content, ui);

// just for fun, a layerUI which can be used to debug component alignement
public class DebugLayerUI extends LayerUI {
    private Map<JComponent, Integer> markThem;

    public DebugLayerUI(JComponent child) {
        markThem = new HashMap<>();
        markThem.put(child, SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
    }

    public void add(JComponent child, int direction) {
        markThem.put(child,  direction);
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        super.paint(g, c);
        g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        for ( Entry<JComponent, Integer> entry : markThem.entrySet()) {
           JComponent child = entry.getKey(); 
           if (SwingConstants.VERTICAL == entry.getValue()) {
               Point p = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(child, 
                       new Point(0, 0),
                       c);
               g.drawLine(p.x, 0, p.x, c.getHeight());
           } else if (SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL == entry.getValue()) {
               int baseline = child.getBaseline(child.getWidth(), child.getHeight());
               if (baseline > 0) {
                   Point p = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(child, 
                           new Point(0, baseline), c);
                   g.drawLine(0, p.y, c.getWidth(), p.y);
               }
           }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: time to create a wiki for MigLayout here, really,